# clean url on iis server

Tags: php, iis, url

Hallo, can someone tell me how to get clean url' s on the IIS server where my site is hosted. I already emailed them, but I don' t count on any response anytime soon.

with clean url, I mean
to use path separators instead off variables like: ?url=bla

actually, same as stack overflow

problem with IIS is that it does not have htaccess

thanks, Richard

Comment: Er, you might want to be a little more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to know about URL rewriting. If so it really depends on your hosting provider and whether they have a rewriting module for IIS loaded on your server such as ISAPI rewrite.

Comment: I am on digitalibiz.com

Is there a way to find out if they have it installed?

Comment: I had a quick look there and couldn't see if they have any rewrite modules enabled, I did however notice that they have a live support feature (it's currently offline so I suppose that it's only available during working hours) I'd suggest you use that to ask them.

Comment: They just got back to me, they say it is beta on some servers?
I reply'd back to ask if it was installed on mine

Comment: I think they have the live chat offline all the time, because I try'd that all different houers.

Answer (score 1):

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/

Do notice that this is a module and has to be installed, hopefully your host have this installed or are willing to install modules.